# Como pegar o resultado do select e montar o HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html

O meu problema é :

Tenho um campo **data inicial** e um campo **data final** e na minha tabela um campo **data**. O usuário vai digitar uma **data de inicio** e uma **data de fim**, e no banco eu verifico se tem dados incluídos entre essas datas. Caso tenha é possível que exista diversos dados entre essas datas. E o meu real problema é .. Como montar o HTML para o Usuário?

Ex:

`Data Inicial : 02/05/2008    Data Final : 05/07/2012`

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <font  size="-1">Data inicial :</font>
    </td>
    <td >
        <input name="tx_data_inic" id="id_data_inic" type="text"  maxlength="10"  size="5">
    </td>
    <td >
        <font  size="-1">Data final :</font>
    </td>
    <td >
        <input name="tx_dt_fina" id="id_data_final" type="text"  maxlength="10" size="5">
        <button type="button" onClick="f_veri_datas();"></button>                       
    </td>
</tr>
```

Select verifica se tem dados na tabela:

```
$w_querybusca="SELECT * FROM sai_cad_datas
                    INNER JOIN sai_cad_cara
                    ON sai_cad_cara.fk_seq_data = sai_cad_datas.seq_data    
    where sai_cad_datas.dt_nota between '$w_tx_dt_inic' and '$w_tx_dt_fina';";
```

Ai em baixo monta no HTML os dados do resultado. Não sei se a maneira mais correta seria utilizar um radio button onde um while vai montando conforme o numero de dados achados.

```
1 - dados do resultado

2 - dados do resultado

3 - dados do resultado
```

Comment: Sim, é possível.

Comment: Como então @Renan?

Comment: Filtre os dados exatamente como você falou, e exiba apenas eles. Você mesmo diz que já tem a consulta pronta. O que você tentou que não deu certo?

Comment: Sim eu tenho a consulta pronta pegando os campos. O meu problema, é que preciso mostrar ao usuário os campos para ele selecionar qual ele quer "editar"! E sim, não sei como mostrar eles!

Comment: Sugiro editar a pergunta para focar no que você precisa. "Como faço para exibir dados de uma tabela..." ou algo do tipo. Me parece que o que você precisa é pegar o resultado da consulta e montar o HTML, certo? Eu adoraria poder ajudar mas PHP não é meu forte :(

Comment: Isso @Renan, necessito pegar o resultado e montar o HTML! Está tudo bem, irei fazer as edições apropriadas para melhor entendimento!

Comment: Velho isso ainda ta meio incompleto... como você gostaria que funcionasse? Com ajax? Você tem lá o retorno do Banco de dados, como seria o ambiente que mostra o resultado?
Uma tabela?

Comment: Resumindo: traduza sua pergunta em forma de código e descrição do seu ambiente. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Vide: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Suponho que deveria ser por um laço criando radio / button / ...!

Comment: Está faltando a parte que chama o HTML desejado no seu código (ou se quer usar `<form>`, por exemplo). E sua query está aonde? Ponha o contexto em que ela ocorre, pois assim as respostas podem ser melhor elaboradas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade é bem simples montar o seu HTML pelo resultado da sua pesquisa. Como você mencionou, por radio seria assim:

```
    $w_querybusca = "SELECT * FROM sai_cad_datas
                     INNER JOIN sai_cad_cara
                     ON sai_cad_cara.fk_seq_data = sai_cad_datas.seq_data    
                     WHERE sai_cad_datas.dt_nota
                         BETWEEN '$w_tx_dt_inic'AND '$w_tx_dt_fina';";

    $w_queryresult=f_class_conecta_bd($w_querybusca);

    while($w_registro = pg_fetch_object($w_queryresult))
    {
        print('<input type="radio" name = rb_peri </input>');
        print('campo que quer mostrar');
    }
```

Dentro do **while** ele vai montar um **radio** de todos os dados do **resultado**, mostrando os campos que você determinar!

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode fazer isso de duas maneiras utilizando `PHP` e/ou `JS` . . . a primeira é montando a `Query` em `PHP`, executando ela e montando na própria página... nesse caso você deve ter uma conexão com o banco, deixo aqui um exemplo mais simples possivel:

**Utilizando PHP/BD_PDO:**

```
        <table id="tabela" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Dia</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            require_once ("cmd_sql.php"); // uma biblioteca que utilizo pra criar a conexão com o banco, utilizando BD_PDO . . . de uma pesquisada sobre

            $varConsulta = ConsultaLista();
            $i=0;
            if ($varConsulta) {
                foreach ($varConsulta as $lin) {
                    $varDia = $varConsulta[$i]['DESCRICAO'];

                    $linhas = "";

                    $linhas .= "<td>" . $varDia . "</td>";

                    echo "<tr>" . $linhas . "</tr>";
                    $i++;
                }
            }

            function ConsultaLista() {
            $sql = new cmd_SQL();   


            $bd['sql'] = "O seu select aqui";
            $rs = $sql->pesquisar($bd);

            return $rs;
            }

            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Utilizando JS/Ajax/BD_PDO:**

```
function carregaDia() {
    var varXML = carrega_XML('SuaBibliotecaQueCarregaOsDados.php', 'filtro=CarregaDia', 'xml');
    var nfaixa = valor_XML(varXML, 'n_reg', 0);
    var tabela = "";
    if (nfaixa > 0) {
        tabela +="<table width='100%'><thead><th>DIA</th></thead><tbody>";
        var dia = "";
        for (i = 0; i < nfaixa; i++) {
            dia = valor_xml(varXML, 'DIA', i);
            tabela += "<tr><td>" + dia+ "</td></tr>";
        }
      tabela += "</tbody</table>"
     document.getElementById('seuCampoQueCarregaATabela').value = tabela;
    }
}
```

Detalhe as funções `carrega_XML` e `valor_XML` são funções que voce deve adequar segundo as suas necessidades... em geral a primeira so cria um `XML` puro, a segunda seleciona o valor de interesse e deixa de acordo que deve ser exibida

ENFIM.... é muito relativo, depende do modo que você queira trabalhar.... se a página for dinamica, sugiro o `JS/Ajax`, se for estática, `PHP`

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja isso que você deseja:

## Neste exemplo estou usando o MySQL

**script.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "exemplo.php", 
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    $("#tabela").append("<tr><td>"+data["dataInicio"]+"</td> <td>"+data["dataFim"]+"</td>");
  }
});
</script>
```

**exemplo.php**

```
<?php
    $consultaSql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE (dataInicio BETWEEN parametro_dataInicio AND dataFim BETWEEN parametro_dataFim)";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    //Atribuo a variavel result o retorno da consulta
    while($result = mysql_fetch_row($query)){  
        //Retorno um Json
        echo json_encode($result);      
    } 
?>
```

**exemplo.html**

```
<form method="post">
    <table id="tabela">
        <tr>
            <td>Data Inicio</td>
            <td>Data Fim</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="date" name="dataInicio" /></td>
            <td><input type="date" name="dataFim" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="pesquisar" value="Pesquisar" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</form>
```